# Wildcard use updating 7zip Sfx with similar titles

Tags: batch-file, wildcard, 7zip

I have 4 different Sfx 7Zip files I need to download and update 1 file in either depending on circumstance.

The file names of the zips vary slightly depending on content and function but all have the word AUTO in the title.

I am updating each file with this command with no problem, however I am looking to simplify the update code. I have a line per installer to update a certain file But I would like just one line that would update whatever version of the file downloaded.

```
"%~dp0Config\7za.exe" u "%~dp0Installer1Auto.exe" "%~dp0Config\config.cfg"
"%~dp0Config\7za.exe" u "%~dp0Installer2Auto.exe" "%~dp0Config\config.cfg"
"%~dp0Config\7za.exe" u "%~dp0Installer3Auto.exe" "%~dp0Config\config.cfg"
"%~dp0Config\7za.exe" u "%~dp0Installer4Auto.exe" "%~dp0Config\config.cfg"
```

How can I use a wildcard (or similar) to only have one line of code regardless of what version of the sfx I downloaded.

I was thinking something like below (but doesn't work)...

```
"%~dp0Config\7za.exe" u "%~dp0*Auto*.exe" "%~dp0Config\config.cfg"
```

"or"

```
"%~dp0Config\7za.exe" u "%~dp0*Installer.exe" "%~dp0Config\config.cfg"
```

Any tips would be excellent, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /L %%q in (1,1,4) do "%~dp0Config\7za.exe" u "%~dp0Installer%%qAuto.exe" "%~dp0Config\config.cfg"
```

or

```
for %%q in (1 2 3 4) do "%~dp0Config\7za.exe" u "%~dp0Installer%%qAuto.exe" "%~dp0Config\config.cfg"
```

The first starts setting `%%q` to 1 then increases `%%q` by 1 until it reaches 4.

The second sets `%%q` to the values 1..4 in turn.

The advantage of the second method is that if you want to process files where the name variant is `Wibble, wobble, wubble, and flob` then it's as simple as changing the code to

```
for %%q in (Wibble wobble wubble flob)...
```

Also, it's possible to gate the command if necessary like:

```
for /L %%q in (1,1,4) do if exist "%~dp0Config\7za.exe" "%~dp0Config\7za.exe" u "%~dp0Installer%%qAuto.exe" "%~dp0Config\config.cfg"
```

which would avoid executing `2`,`3` and `4` if only `1` exists.

---

To execute against all *.exe files found in the directory `%~dp0`, use

```
FOR %%a IN ("%~dp0\*.exe") DO ECHO("%~dp0Config\7za.exe" u "%%~fa" "%~dp0Config\config.cfg"
```

where `*.exe` could be `installer*auto.exe` if required.

Comment: Excellent, works perfect! Thanks for detailed and multi option answer.

Comment: Actually is there a way to tweak it so that the name of the exe is irrelevant, so whatever *.exe is downloaded the update will run on whatever file is present? Thanks

Comment: Hi, to make all exe code work I needed to tweak it a bit, maybe you want to edit the answer (echo & bracket at the end, works great!!                                                                                                    FOR %%a IN ("%~dp0\auto*.exe") DO ("%~dp0Config\7za.exe" u "%%~fa" "%~dp0Config\config.cfg")

Comment: Hehe... Although traditionally the character following `echo` is a space, there is a set of characters which may succeed the `o` and produce virtually the same result. Of these, `(` is particularly useful because `echo %something%` where `something` is undefined will report `echo is on/off` but `echo(%something%` where `something` is undefined will produce a new line. Despite appearances, the `(` here plays absolutely no part in the tradition "nesting" of commands. Certainly a trick for young players - one of the quirks of batch that make it the black art it is.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Could I sync updated installers.exe's  to folders of the exact same name  on a USB. On the USB we have "F:\installer-auto1\installer-auto1.exe" and  "F:\installer-auto2\installer-auto2.exe" I was looking at the code and thinking it's easy by doing an xcopy of "%%~fa" to the drive but of course there is a folder involved but exact same name as exe. Copy and commands I'm used to so no worries there,  I'm wondering if this is a good idea echo F| XCOPY "%%~fa" /y "%DRV%\auto*\%%~fa" Hope that makes sense? ;-)

Comment: the folder name doesn't come through "%DRV%\auto*\%%~fa" the output is that it is looking for a folder called Auto* and not  installer-auto2 or installer-auto1 etc. How can I make "%%~fa" drop the .exe or am I up the wrong tree? thanks for fast reply!

Comment: Use `*auto*.exe` in place of `auto*` (*anything*auto*anything*.exe) to select the `.exe` file. `installer-auto*.exe` if that suits better. Change `~f` to `~dpn` (Full to DrivePathName) - see for /f from the prompt for docco

Comment: echo F| XCOPY "%%~fa" /y "%DRV%\%%~fa" works and copies exe to root of USB but I cant get it to copy to  "%DRV%\foldernameofexe\%%~fa" e.g "%DRV%\installer1auto\%%~fa" tried changing *auto* and %%~f / %%~fdpn but no joy

Comment: Change ~f to ~dpn - where there was ~f in the command (fullname) change it to `~dpn` (DrivePathName). You report `%%~fdpn` (too many `f`s) and you do realise that `%%~xyzH` means `apply the modifiers `x`, `y` and `z` to `%%H` don't you? Therefore, since the filename is in `%%a`, `%%~fa` means "the full filename of `%%a`", `%%~dpna` means "the DrivePathName" of `%%a` (ie. full filename without the extension.)

Comment: ah ha the penny has dropped I only need the name which is N. I have achieved this part using this test command..echo F| XCOPY "%%~fa" /y "G:\%%~na" after the initial update of exe it now syncs and overwrites the copy on USB full code is if anyone ever needs to do this....FOR %%a IN ("%~dp0\*auto*.exe") DO ("%~dp0Config\7za.exe" u "%%~fa" "%~dp0Config\config.cfg" & FOR %%a IN ("%~dp0\*auto*.exe") DO echo F| XCOPY "%%~fa" /y "G:\%%~na") - Many thanks magoo!